# Sort tall images into one folder, wide into another

Tags: images, file-management, windows-10, image-viewer

I have a large image collection on my full windows 10 tablet.

- I start with hundreds of images
- Some of them are taller than wide -> I want them to go in one folder
- Some of them are wilder than tall -> I want them to go into a different folder

What software would you recommend to accomplish this?

**Why I even want to do this:**

It's a tablet. Tall pictures are nice to look at in portrait mode for the tablet. It'd be great to separate out the tall pictures.

No coding ability but perhaps if something is very simple, my school allows us to install Matlab for free. Also a commenter below mentioned python.

Comment: "`I don't think sorting just by pixels width will work because the images vary greatly in dimensions/resolution
1`" - if you have a requirement other than `sort on width >= height`, please state it. Once you know what your requirements are, we can try to help you

Comment: width >= height is my only requirement

Comment: Then why did you say "`I don't think sorting just by pixels width will work`"? Without clear requirements, it is difficult for us to help you. I see that you updated your question, which is good, but please bear in mind for future questions, that the clearer the description, the better the answer. Help us to help you :-)  I don't suppose you can code? Because this would be very simple in Python

Comment: Sorting by pixel width will not work. For example, there are wide pictures that happen to have alot of vertical pixels (because they are big overall).  Are the requirements clear now? width>= height is all. What else would be useful to help make it clear? Is there a simple script I can run after downloading a program in python? I cannot code.

Comment: Your first 3 statements there seem to contradict, but "`width>= height is all`" is clear enough.

Comment: Which 3 statements? This one "Sorting by pixel width will not work." ? What do you think I should edit in this post to make it more clear?

Comment: As far as those statements not making sense, imagine a 3000 wide by 2000 pixel tall image. It is obviously a wide image, but because it is 2000 pixels tall (which is alot in my folder), if you sort images by pixel height alone, it will have higher vertical pixel number than many images(such as a 500 pixel wide by 1000 pixel tall image, which would obviously be tall). So we can't just sort by # vertical pixels alone. But we could sort by whether width>=tall which is all I'm asking.

Comment: D'oh!! How stupid of me. Yes, I see now what you mean : `width>= height` :-)

Comment: You want to sort by aspect ratio: Landscape: width/height >= 1; Portrait: width/height < 1. I could do it in any number of languages but I don't know of anything off the shelf.

Comment: This could be easily be done with powershell.... I tried to find something off the shelf in software such as hygeia, dropit etc but I don't have a windows pc at the moment to download and test...

Comment: Well my school let's us download Matlab. Time to learn some basic programming. If I can get to a point of GUI click a folder and figure out how to move files that might do it. If I have to copy image files, it might crash my crappy computer